# How to expose a port in heroku?

Tags: docker, heroku

So I have deployed an app on heroku, and when deployed, it says it's running on localhost:5000. I want to expose this port using the $PORT variable. What is the exact command for doing this? This is relevant: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime#dockerfile-commands-and-runtime, but how to really expose the port? This is what my Dockerfile looks like:

```
# We will use Ubuntu for our image
FROM ubuntu:latest

# Updating Ubuntu packages

ARG CLOJURE_TOOLS_VERSION=1.10.1.507


RUN apt-get -qq update && apt-get -qq -y install curl wget bzip2 openjdk-8-jdk-headless \
    && curl -sSL https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -o /tmp/miniconda.sh \
    && bash /tmp/miniconda.sh -bfp /usr/local \
    && rm -rf /tmp/miniconda.sh \
    && conda install -y python=3 \
    && conda update conda \
    && curl -o install-clojure https://download.clojure.org/install/linux-install-${CLOJURE_TOOLS_VERSION}.sh \
    && chmod +x install-clojure \
    && ./install-clojure && rm install-clojure \
    && wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/technomancy/leiningen/stable/bin/lein \
    && chmod a+x lein \
    && mv lein /usr/bin \
    && apt-get -qq -y autoremove \
    && apt-get autoclean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /var/log/dpkg.log \
    && conda clean --all --yes


ENV PATH /opt/conda/bin:$PATH

RUN conda create -n pyclj python=3.6 && conda install -n pyclj numpy mxnet

## To install pip packages into the pyclj environment do
RUN conda run -n pyclj python3 -mpip install numpy
#COPY . .
RUN lein uberjar
RUN java $JVM_OPTS -cp target/myapp.jar clojure.main -m myapp.application --server.port=$PORT
```

The Dockerfile example here https://github.com/heroku/alpinehelloworld/blob/master/Dockerfile shows a gunicorn command, but my project hasn't used gunicorn so far. How do I configure my Dockerfile so that my app uses the $PORT environment variable?

I'm using aleph.io:

```
(ns myapp.application
  (:gen-class)
  (:require ;; more requires 
              [system.components.aleph :refer [new-web-server]]
            ))

(defn app-system [config]
  (component/system-map
   :routes     (new-endpoint home-routes)
   :middleware (new-middleware {:middleware (:middleware config)})
   :handler    (-> (new-handler :router :bidi
                    )
                   (component/using [:routes :middleware]))
   :http       (-> (new-web-server (:http-port config) :handler)
                   (component/using [:handler]))
   :server-info (server-info (:http-port config))))

(defn -main [& _]
  (let [config (config)]
    (-> config
        app-system
        component/start)))
```

Answer (score 0):

The log entry `"(...) when deployed, it says it's running on localhost:5000"` states that the listening host is restricted to `localhost`. So your server can't be reached from the internet (or by using the heroku domain).

Independent of the server you are using, you need to set the listening host to `0.0.0.0`. Without knowing your server framework I would assume that you have to edit the last line in your docker file (and add `--server.host=0.0.0.0`):

```
RUN java $JVM_OPTS -cp target/myapp.jar clojure.main -m myapp.application --server.port=$PORT --server.host=0.0.0.0
```

Comment: Appending the last command with --server.host=0.0.0.0 shows the same in remote log during the push: Started myapp on http://localhost:5000

Comment: What (web)server framework are you using for your app?

Comment: I'm using https://aleph.io:

`(defn app-system [config]
  (component/system-map
   :routes     (new-endpoint home-routes)
   :middleware (new-middleware {:middleware (:middleware config)})
   :handler    (-> (new-handler :router :bidi
                    )
                   (component/using [:routes :middleware]))
   :http       (-> (new-web-server (:http-port config) :handler)
                   (component/using [:handler]))
   :server-info (server-info (:http-port config))))`

My edit has the almost the same code with better formatting.